# Different height for column headers in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, aspxgridview

I want First column with less height for a GridView as shown in the First pic .
I tried setting different header height from C# and from Aspx . But no use .
It renders as shown in the second pic . Is there any way to make it as in the first one ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can think to instead set the background color to white and the forecolor to black for the first row of the first column (from the itemdatabound event). That will give the illusion that the cell is a different height.